# Python 3.5.2 strptime can't read output from strftime when using same formatting string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, strftime, strptime

I'm having a bizarre issue with time.strptime in Python 3.5.2. For testing purposes, I'm generating a time string with time.strftime, then attempting to parse that string with time.strptime, using the same formatting string in both cases.

Sample code illustrating this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_test=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', time.localtime())
    print (time_test)
    test=time.strptime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', time_test)
    print (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', test))
```

The results I'm seeing:

```
2017-02-01T11:23:53-0800
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_time.py", line 8, in <module>
    test=time.strptime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', time_test)
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 504, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/Python-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z' does not match format '2017-02-01T11:23:53-0800'
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh: I got the arguments to time.strptime reversed.

The correct code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_test=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', time.localtime())
    print (time_test)
    test=time.strptime(time_test, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
    print (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', test))
```